# Collection name in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Why would a database named 'blog' not allow a record insert and also give no return error and why would a database named 'blogs' allow a record inserts and return errors?**

---

I just spent several hours going through all my code thinking I did something wrong.  I have written many mongoose connected apps but when using the following it would return success but not insert the record and return no error as to why:

```
mongooose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/blog');
```

After banging my head against a wall for a bit I decided to change the database name:

```
mongooose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/blogs');
```

It works!  But why would this name convention matter? I can't find anything in the documentation for [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org) or [Mongoosejs](http://mongoosejs.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm fairly certain mongodb doesn't care about database name "blog" vs "blogs". However, do note that mongoose has the questionably-helpful feature of silently queueing up operations while the database connection is still not established and then firing them off if/when the database connection is ready. That could be causing your confusion. To test that theory, pass a callback to `mongoose.connect` and put a `console.log` in the callback so you know exactly when the connection is ready.